# VBA Global Object Variables

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with global variables. The code I have below needs to be accessed by a multiple Modules and a User form. My attempts to make them a global failed.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Some.xlsm")
   Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Some Sheet")
```

I have tried making a module to hold them but ran into a runtime error. My program works fine if I copy this code to each function that uses it but that becomes messy. I would like to set it up to just have to change the two lines in order to affect the entire file. When I made a new module it did not like Dim.

Edit:

```
    Public wb As Workbook
    Public ws As Worksheet

Public Sub modVariables()
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("V:\My Stuff\Templates\Work Order Batch Creation Template\Sandbox\WorkOrderDatabase.xlsm")
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Description - Processes")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare them as public variables like the following:

```
Public wb As Workbook
Public ws As Worksheet
```

Comment: They are used in a private sub. When I do that it says invalid attribute in sub or function. Were would I put them in a new module? Or Can I just put them outside the private function?

Comment: Then declare them in a seperate module as public variables.
For example create a module modVariables just for public variables.

Comment: I am sorry I am not the best at this yet. I tried what you said and still get an error. This time it says invalid outside procedure.

Comment: Do you set your variables in this module as well? You are only allowed to declare them outside a sub. But your set commands have to be inside your sub

Comment: I have the public values outside the sub and I set them inside the sub. I posted the module above. It shoots a runtime error '91'

Comment: No, you didnt get me right: 

Put the declarations of your variables in a seperate module (container with code in it). 
This module only holds the following lines:
     `Public wb As Workbook`
    `Public ws As Worksheet`

And now your sub looks like the following:

    `Sub mySub()`
    `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Some.xlsm")`
    `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Some Sheet")`
    `End Sub`

Comment: @Daniel it might be clearer to say: re-declare those variables in each module that you want to use them. They won't interfere with what's in the other module since the sub is private

Answer (score 0):

Thats how it should look like:

[image]